# Sorting a linked list (swapping nodes)

Tags: python, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to sort a LinkedList containing of such nodes:

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self, data, next=None):
       self.data, self.next = data, next
```

The idea is to get a sequence (list/tuple/string) from which a LinkedList is created:

```
def __init__(self, seq):
    self.front = self.Node(None)
    node = self.front
    for item in seq:
        node.next = self.Node(item)
        node = node.next
```

The logic of the sort is that in each iteration you go through the linkedlist, compare each item with the first, if its smaller/greater then you perform a swap, continue going through the linked list and do the same comparation and operation. Shown here:

```
    def min_sort(self, reverse):
        self.count = 0
        first = self.front
        while first.next is not None:
            print(self.get_list())
            self.progress(first, reverse)
            self.count += 1
            first = first.next

    def progress(self, first, reverse):
        node = first
        if (node is None): return
        while True:
            node = node.next
            if node is None or node.next is None: break

            if (reverse):
                if (first.next.data < node.next.data):
                    self.vymen(first, node, node.next)
            else:
                if (first.next.data > node.next.data):
                    self.vymen(first, node, node.next)
```

The issue is with the swap itself (function self.vymen(...)), where with basic LinkedList of numbers it usually works, however when loaded with a string e.g. "I code in Python", the spaces dont get swapped to the correct position making the whole result messed up.
The swap itself is:

```
    def vymen(self, first, prev, swap):
        prevX, currX, prevY, currY = first, first.next, prev, swap

        if (self.front.next.data == swap.data): return
        if (currX is None or currY is None): return

        if (currX != prevY):
            if (prevX is not None): prevX.next = currY
            else: self.front = currY

            if (prevY is not None): prevY.next = currX
            else: self.front = currX

            temp = currX.next
            currX.next = currY.next
            currY.next = temp

        else:
            temp = currY.next
            currX.next = temp
            currY.next = currX
            prevX.next = currY
```

Its really just an issue with the spaces as I can see and I dont understand whats the issue, since it swaps the first space on the beginning but not the rest. I would be thankful if someone would be able to point out a mistake or give me an idea whats happening :)

Comment: Please provide the actual calls you make with the specific input that poses a problem, and be concrete about the output you get, and what you expect instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- The following statement in `vymen` is the cause of trouble:

  ```
  if (self.front.next.data == swap.data): return
  ```

  Its intention is to avoid an unnecessary swap when the data of the swapped nodes are equal. But then it should not reference `self.front.next`, but `curX` -- as *that* is the node that is to be swapped:

  ```
  if currX.data == currY.data:
      return
  ```
- The `if` condition that follows after it, is not useful at this point:

  ```
  if (currX is None or currY is None): return
  ```

  ...as we already referenced `swap.data` (i.e. `currY.data`) at this point. So if this really were possible, it should be checked before referencing `currY.data` or `currX.data`. So combine it with the previous `if`:

  ```
  if currX is None or currY is None or currX.data == currY.data:
      return
  ```
- The main loop in `progress` will skip a node when two *consecutive*(!) nodes are swapped. In that case, before the call to `vymen`, `node` will become `currX` that will hop over `node.next`. And so *after* the call, `node` will still reference the same node, but its position in the list is one further. By consequence, there is a node that will not haven an iteration of the loop. This is a cause of getting wrong outputs, even with plain numbers. To solve this, you could adapt `vymen` so it will *return* the node that will be at the same position as `node` was at the start of the call. The caller should then re-assign that reference to its `node` variable.

Some other remarks:

- In Python it is not needed to put parentheses around `if` conditions
- In `vymen`, the following condition should always be true:

  ```
  if (prevX is not None): prevX.next = currY
  else: self.front = currY
  ```

  This should never be true, because you have designed your linked list to have a sentinel node at its front (having value `None`). So you don't even want `self.front = currY` to ever execute! `prevX` should never be `None`. It never is `None` in the way you call this function either. So just remove this construct and just assign:

  ```
  prevX.next = currY
  ```

  The same should happen with the `if..else` that follows it.
- The `vymen` shoudn't need its last argument (`swap`), as it should always be the value of `prev.next`. So the function could start like this:

  ```
  def vymen(self, first, prev):
      prevX, currX, prevY, currY = first, first.next, prev, prev.next
  ```

  And the call would be (note also the assignment of the return value):

  ```
  node = self.vymen(first, node)
  ```
- It is a pity that right after the function header of `vymen`, you define new variables for exactly the same as `first` and `prev`: `prevX` and `prevY`. Why not name the parameter variables like that immediately?
- It is a pity that in `progress` you have an `if` with a  `break` as the first statement in the `while True` body. You can better rewrite this so to have the condition in the `while` statement

Taking it all together, this is the resulting code for the two methods that had problems:

```
    def progress(self, first, reverse):
        if first is None or first.next is None:
            return
        node = first.next
        while node.next:  # Use a condition to exit instead of break
            if reverse:
                if first.next.data < node.next.data:
                    # Take the return value, and pass one argument less
                    node = self.vymen(first, node)  
            else:
                if first.next.data > node.next.data:
                    # Take the return value, and pass one argument less
                    node = self.vymen(first, node)
            node = node.next

    def vymen(self, prevX, prevY):  # Use the desired variable names
        # No need for the swap argument
        currX, currY = prevX.next, prevY.next

        # Corrected comparison of the two nodes' data, and put the 
        #   conditions in the right order:
        if currX is None or currY is None or currX.data == currY.data:
            return prev # return the node at the position of prev 

        if currX != prevY:
            # Make the following assignments unconditionally
            prevX.next = currY
            prevY.next = currX

            temp = currX.next
            currX.next = currY.next
            currY.next = temp
            # Return the reference of the node that is in the position
            #    of prev: it is still in the same position:
            return prev
        else:
            temp = currY.next
            currX.next = temp
            currY.next = currX
            prevX.next = currY
            # Return the reference of the node that is in the position
            #    of prev: it has moved, so now it is...:
            return currY
```

Comment: After all I figured out some issues, which you kindly mentioned. By all means, this works just fine until I get a linkedlist filled with 500+ random strings where it fails on max recursion depth (timeout error). I will be looking at this for sure and thank you very much! :)

Comment: OK. This code alone cannot produce a max recursion depth error.  There is no recursion. You can see it run [here](https://www.online-python.com/xiuHMKsa1D) with an input string of 900 characters. It takes 2 seconds to run and output the sorted list. Possibly your implementation of `get_list` is recursive?